# Fetch the user details from LDAP Active directory from MULTIPLE domains using Java

Tags: active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, active-directory-group

My requirement is, based on user id I need to fetch the user details (like first name and last name ) from LDAP active directory.
But the catch here is we don't know in which domain user will be exists. And we have around 12 different domains each has different provider URL. 
Currently I am able to fetch the user details from one domain when I provide the input as -
1. providerURL (this is domain specific, each domain has different URL) 
2. username
3. password

Since the problem is we don't know in which domain user will be exists, I don't want to make a sequential or parallel calls to search user one by one in each domain . 
Is there any other way around so that in one call I can search particular user across all available domains?
looking any simple Java based or spring-java based solution.

We  heard there is global Catlog in LDAP active directory but not aware of it much.  Is it possible that if we create some global account (which will act as super user) then using that global account details we can then search particular user across all domains.

I am not aware of LDAP active directory server structure, if I can have 
service account (with special role access permissions) so that using it I can search user details across all domains.

Another query is -> instead of global service account, If we create a service account in one domain with some extra special role access permissions then can I use it to search user from any other domains ?

Please suggest the solution approach for our project requirement.

Currently I am able to fetch the user details from one domain using that using below code->

public class LDAPExaminer {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LDAPExaminer ldapExaminer = new LDAPExaminer();

    ldapExaminer.printUserBasicAttributes("userId", ldapExaminer.getLdapContext());
}

public LdapContext getLdapContext() {
    LdapContext ctx = null;
    try {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");


        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user@domain");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://example.domain.com");

        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        System.out.println("Attempting to Connect...");

        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful.");
    } catch (NamingException nex) {
        System.out.println("LDAP Connection: FAILED");
        nex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ctx;
}

private void printUserBasicAttributes(String username, LdapContext ctx) {
    try {

        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String[] attrIDs = {"distinguishedName", "UN", "givenname", "mail", "telephonenumber", "canonicalName", "userAccountControl", "accountExpires"};
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);


        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("DC=example,DC=domain,DC=com", "sAMAccountName=" + username, constraints);

        if (answer.hasMore()) {
            Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
            System.out.println(attrs.get("distinguishedName"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("givenname"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("sn"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("mail"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("telephonenumber"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("canonicalName"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("userAccountControl"));
            System.out.println(attrs.get("accountExpires"));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid User");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The Global Catalog works the same way as a normal LDAP connection, but it just runs from a different port. So you just need to specify the GC port of 3268:

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://example.domain.com:3268");
```

That's it.

The GC will let you find all accounts in the same AD forest, which is a group of domains that have a complete trust in each other. Accounts on one domain can authenticate on the other and permissions can be easily granted between them.

You will have to know how your 12 domains are organized. You will have to make one search for each AD forest. You can't make one search that will find accounts in separate forests.

There are other caveats, like some AD attributes are not replicated to the Global Catalog. For example, the `accountExpires` attribute that you are looking for is not replicated to the GC. If you [look up the attribute on the Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-accountexpires), you'll see that "In Global Catalog" is "False".

Comment: already tried with port 3268 , but its not working to fetch from other domain. Seems AD forests are independent in our organisation.

Comment: If they are in separate forests, then you have no choice but to query them separately.